# Convert INT64 String to INT64 number in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

[This API](https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/sponsored-brands/3-0/openapi#/Keywords/updateKeywords) expects a parameter to be INT64 not INT64 string. I have a INT64 string `144349945283010116`. And I need same as number.

When I tried to `parseInt('144349945283010116', 10)` it rounds off to `144349945283010100` which changes its id.

I tried node-int64, longfn, BigInt but none of them worked

Comment: How exactly does the API expect the parameter? Is it a GET or POST request? url-encoded or JSON? etc.

Comment: @ChrisG PUT request as JSON body - https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/sponsored-brands/3-0/openapi#/Keywords/updateKeywords

Comment: The straightforward but ugly way is to manually compose the JSON string and insert the int64 string. An alternative is to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-int64) however I'm not sure whether you can use that as-is in browser-side JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need to send the number to an API you don't actually need to worry about actually representing it inside of JS as a (big) number. Just send it:

```
  const number = '144349945283010116';
  const stringToSend = `{"keywordId": ${number}}`;
```